# electron launch timeout 3000ms after update playwright to 1.35.1

Tags: node.js, electron, playwright-test

We have recently migrated to V1.31.1 for playwright. Earlier everything was fine. But with this update all tests are giving the same issue.

TimeoutError: electronApplication.firstWindow: Timeout 30000ms exceeded while waiting for event "window"

```
   at Utils.tsx:51

  49 |
> 50 |     (await electronApp.firstWindow()).evaluate(() => {
     |                        ^
  51 |       localStorage.clear();
  52 |     });
```

Expected : Expect to open the electron app and run the test script

Comment: the actual error is in line 50. Removed a comment above